# Composing subexponential L-function

Tags: cryptanalysis, complexity, number-theory

Suppose $y=f(x)$ and $z=g(y)$ such that $y\in L_x[a,b]$ and $z\in L_y[c,d]$, where $L$ is the usual sub-exponential asymptotic notation

$$L_x[a,b] = \exp\left((b+o(1))(\log x)^a(\log\log x)^{1-a}\right)$$.

Can $z$ be written as $L_x[a',b']$ for some $a',b'$? I think the answer is yes, based on the following (using the $o(1)$ to hide a lot of terms):

$$\begin{align}
\log z = & (d+o(1))(\log y)^c(\log\log y)^{1-c}\\
= & (d+o(1))\left((b+o(1))(\log x)^a(\log\log x)^{1-a}\right)^c(\log\log y)^{1-c}\\
= & (b^cd+o(1))(\log x)^{ac}(\log\log x)^{c-ac}(\log\log y)^{1-c}\\
= &  (b^cd+o(1))(\log x)^{ac}(\log\log x)^{c-ac}\left(\log(b+o(1)) + a\log\log x + (1-a)(\log\log\log x)^{1-a}\right)^{1-c}\\
= &  (b^cd+o(1))(\log x)^{ac}(\log\log x)^{c-ac}(\log\log x)^{1-c}\left(a+o(1)\right)^{1-c}\\
= & (a^{1-c}b^cd+o(1))(\log x)^{ac}(\log\log x)^{1-ac}\\
= & \log L_x[ac, a^{1-c}b^cd]
\end{align}$$
This confuses me because for $a,c<1$, then $ac<a$. But that would imply that $L_x[ac,a^{a-c}b^cd] = o(L_x[a,b])$, which implies $z=o(y)$, but that does not make sense if $z$ grows subexponentially with $y$.

Have I made some mistake in my derivation? Is the composition of $L[\cdot, \cdot]$ well-known?

Comment: Suppose the $o(1)$ term is $f(x)$; then $(b+f(x))^c = b^c + b^{c-1}f(x) + \dots + f(x)^c$. $b^{c-i}$ is constant, so all of the terms except $b^c$ should end up in the $o(1)$ term.

Comment: Yes, since $1\notin o(1)$. If we have $b=2$ and $o(1)=1/x$ (for example), then we get $b^c + b^{c-1}/x + \dots + 1/x^c$, which approaches $b^c$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Ok. Yes, that line passes. Clean up.